# Two images with identical physical pixel height are having an offset in height.

Tags: image, css, singularitygs, picturefill

I have built the following in Singularity 
[image: one third two third image raster]

A 1/3 broad image next to a 2/3 broad image and in the next line the other way around. The images are served with picturefill. But my problem is when i narrow the viewport down from the containers max-width towards the breakpoint (750px) where the images switch from a two "column" layout to a one column it differ in height even the source files have the exact same physical height in pixel. They differ sometimes a few pixel, sometimes only one.

[image: differing height]

the reduced setup behind is the following (left out retina markup and 2 breakpoints inbetween):

```
<section class="pro-main" role="main">
    <section class="pro-thirds">
        <article class="pro-samples imgparent">
            <a class="p-ov-liner" href="#">
                <span data-picture data-alt="onethird">
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gpfinestsolution-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg"></span>
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gpfinestsolution-eindrittel-341x347.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 750px)"></span>
                    <noscript><img src="/img/projekte-gpfinestsolution-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg" alt="img1"></noscript>
                </span>
                <div class="bottombox"></div>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article class="pro-samples imgparent">
            <a class="p-ov-liner" href="#">
                <span data-picture data-alt="twothird">
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gplab-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg"></span>
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gplab-zweidrittel-704x347.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 750px)"></span>
                    <noscript><img src="/img/projekte-gplab-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg" alt="twothird"></noscript>
                </span>
                <div class="bottombox"></div>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article class="pro-samples imgparent">
            <a class="p-ov-liner" href="#">
                <span data-picture data-alt="twothird">
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gplab-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg"></span>
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gplab-zweidrittel-704x347.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 750px)"></span>
                    <noscript><img src="/img/projekte-gplab-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg" alt="twothird"></noscript>
                </span>
                <div class="bottombox"></div>
            </a>
        </article>
        <article class="pro-samples imgparent">
            <a class="p-ov-liner" href="#">
                <span data-picture data-alt="onethird">
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gpfinestsolution-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg"></span>
                    <span data-src="/img/projekte-gpfinestsolution-eindrittel-341x347.jpg" data-media="(min-width: 750px)"></span>
                    <noscript><img src="/img/projekte-gpfinestsolution-zweidrittel-659x324.jpg" alt="img1"></noscript>
                </span>
                <div class="bottombox"></div>
            </a>
        </article>
    </section>
</section>
```

breakpoint and singularity settings are as follows:

```
// Baseline breaks
$baseline675: 675px 849px;
$baseline850: 850px 1074px;
$baseline1075: 1075px 1199px;
$baselineMAX: 1200px;
// Container breaks
$container600: 600px;
$container750: 750px;
$container850: 850px;
$container990: 990px;
$container1100: 1100px;
$container1200: 1200px;
// Singularity
$grids: 6;
$grids: add-grid(9 at 675px);
$grids: add-grid(12 at 850px);
$grids: add-grid(15 at 1075px);
$grids: add-grid(18 at 1200px);

$gutters: 1/3;

$output:'isolation';
```

the styling:

```
.pro-main,
.pro-thirds {
    @extend %clearfix;
}

.pro-samples {
    @include trailer(0.5);
        &:last-child {
            @include trailer(2);
        }
    @include switch-baseline(850px 1074px) {
        &:nth-child(4n+1) {
            @include isolation-span(4, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+4) {
            @include isolation-span(4, 9, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+2) {
            @include isolation-span(8, 5, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+3) {
            @include isolation-span(8, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
        }
        &:last-child {
            @include trailer(2);
        }
    }
    @include breakpoint(1075px 1199px) {
        &:nth-child(4n+1) {
            @include isolation-span(5, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+4) {
            @include isolation-span(5, 11, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+2) {
            @include isolation-span(10, 6, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+3) {
            @include isolation-span(10, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
        }
        &:last-child {
            @include trailer(2);
        }
    }
    @include breakpoint(1200px) {
        &:nth-child(4n+1) {
            @include isolation-span(6, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+4) {
            @include isolation-span(6, 13, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+2) {
            @include isolation-span(12, 7, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+3) {
            @include isolation-span(12, 1, 'right', $gutter:.5);
        }
        &:last-child {
            @include trailer(2);
        }
    }
}
```

Between the height of the one third and two third images at max width are physically identical also they are aligned at the bottom line. on smaller viewports they differ. and if i remove the gutter with pictures in it the heights still differs. e.g.

```
    @include breakpoint(1075px 1199px) {
        &:nth-child(4n+1) {
            @include isolation-span(5, 1, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+4) {
            @include isolation-span(5, 11, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+2) {
            @include isolation-span(10, 6, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:nth-child(4n+3) {
            @include isolation-span(10, 1, 'right', $gutter:0);
        }
        &:last-child {
            @include trailer(2);
        }
    }
```

If i use, instead of the picturefill markup, just empty article tags and add those two properties to the scss from above the height stays exactly the same on all article elements no matter if they are 1/3 or 2/3.

```
 background:red
 height:10em;
```

with gutter:

[image: red with gutter]

and without:

[image: red without gutter]

Does anyone have an idea what might cause that varying difference in height over the viewports? Me for myself am completely out of ideas. :(

Best regards Ralf

Comment: Please share a minimal demo via http://sassmeister.com/ . If you share it by editing the question, don't forget to write a follow-up comment.

Comment: argl,sorry. i tried to put up an example on sassmeister but two facts stopped me. first i dont have a webspace available at the moment for linking to images from gists (i only have some dropbox space available right now but that doesnt work due to restrictions)and second the changed syntax for singularity and toolkit made me stumble a bit (the output wasn't correct after all). I have a stripped down sample project including images and reduced picturefill code over here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/8578/sample.zip . Meanwhile i try to get the gist going with a non image setup at least.

Comment: Use http://placehold.it/ for pictures. As for changed syntax, Sassmeister is still bundling the good old Singularity 1.1.2.

Comment: uhhh forgive the probably silly question, but where am i able to define which singularity version i am gonna use for a gist in sassmeister? in the control panel i am only able to choose the sass compiler version and syntax. :/

Comment: Not available. Please support [this ticket](https://github.com/jedfoster/SassMeister/issues/88).

Comment: uhhh damn :((((( and done... supported your ticket with a +1 and a brief comment.

Comment: i've put together a small gist now with the new singularity syntax. http://sassmeister.com/gist/9618071 . The picturefill part is removed. Unfortunately i have no idea why the images aren't laid out anymore in the way they are shown in the screenshot above. Initially thought my sass code for the ```.pro-samples```class was correct, but meanwhile i am uncertain if it isn't fundamentally wrong too. And on a sidenote even in the present example i see a slight difference in height in the output. there is a slight visible step between 355x347 and 704x394. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The reason for the difference in images' heights

The reason for the difference in images' heights is mathematical.

For simplicity, let's have a look at the following column system:

```
@include add-grid(4);
@include add-gutter(0.1);
```

The above definition means: four columns of identical width, and between them three (4 - 1) gutters. Each gutter has the width equal to 0.1 width of any column.

Now, given that the width of the container is 1000 px, what will be the width of every column and every gutter?

Let's say that a column is x px wide. Then a gutter will be 0.1x px wide. We can assemble an equation:

```
4x + 3*(0.1x) = 1000
```

Let's solve it:

```
4x + 0.3x = 1000
4.3x = 1000
x = 1000 / 4.3
x = 232.56
```

Every column is ~232.56px wide! And every gutter is 232.56 * 0.1 = 23.256px wide.

Now, let's say we've got two images: 250x250 px and 750x250 px, and we put them into these columns.

The first image will occupy one column and zero gutters. It's width and height will both be equal to 232.56 px.

The second image will occupy three columns and two gutters between those columns. It's width will be equal to 232.56 * 3 + 23.256 * 2 = 744.192px. The height of the second image will be equal to 250 * 744.192 / 750 = 248.064px.

As you can see, the images' heights don't match, and this is expected.

### A solution for the problem

You could use a compound grid to compensate for the difference in heights. This is way more difficult to calculate.

A simpler solution is to slice your images to match your existing grid!

### General recommendations for your grid layout.

1. You use a lot of grid definitions for different breakpoints but across all of them (except for the mobile view), you have the same layout.

   You don't have to redefine grids for every breakpoint. In fact, your responsive layout can be reduced to this definition:

   ```
   +add-grid(3);
   +add-gutter(0.5);
   ```

   For the mobile layout, don't apply any spans. For the layouts starting with the smallest breakpoint, apply the spans and you're good to go.

   Note that you can still apply multiple breakpoints for other styles, e. g. container width.
2. For the isolation spanning to work with multiple rows, apply clearing for the first child  in every row:

   ```
   &:nth-child(3n+1) { clear: both; }
   ```

   Note: this should be done AFTER applying a Singularity span mixin, e. g.:

   ```
   &:nth-child(3n+1) {
     +grid-span(1,1);
     clear: both;
   }
   ```
3. You can use the common `grid-span` mixin instead of the specific `isolation-span`. Isolation is the default spanning technique for the `grid-span` mixin.
4. Don't override direction and gutters for every mixin call unless you're trying to position elements off the declared grid.
5. Don't use varying gutter sizes for adjacent elements, otherwise it will ruin the math.
6. Don't apply duplicate styles under every media query. Ideally, every CSS rule should be declared only once. You can create more specific media query rules if necesary instead of duplicating styles.
7. **UPD:** Oh, and remember that you can declare columns and guttters in the following format:

   ```
   +add-grid(235 235 235 235);
   +add-gutter(20);
   ```

   This is identical to `+add-grid(4); +add-gutter(0.085);` but makes comprehending the numbers much easier.

Comment: phhhhhhheeeeeewwwwwwww at first THANK YOU for that extensive explanation! It took me a while to digest, to grasp and finally understand, at least to some extent. ;) I tried to get things going afterwards and as it seems this one "might" work: http://sassmeister.com/gist/9632917 At least there isn't any grave step in it. Is that a viable solution?

Comment: and one followup question regarding your first point. so far i thought  if i have definied grids for the different viewports like ```add-grid(9 at 675px);```and ```(12 at 850px);``` i have to write for each breakpoint the whole set of nth child conditions again cuz the column count and context differs due to the changed total number of columns for the grid.

Comment: and about your point three i am aware of that i just choose the isolation-span mixin which includes the clearing definition within the mixin and not separately afterwards. looked a bit cleaner for me. and point six i try but still struggling in a few cases. but i am working on it ;)

Comment: So you ended up using an asymmetric grid. This resolves your issue because large images no longer occupy gutters between columns. I did not suggest this way because there's a downside: you have to override your grid definition for every other row. Note that instead of using `layout()` you could simply define grids in place like this: `$grids: 1 2;`, just be sure not to do that in a global scope. (This was possible in 1.1.2, not sure about 1.2.0. Also not sure whether it's a good or bad practice, but i ended up not using a global grid definition at all).

Comment: > and one followup question < // Yes, you're right. Once you defined a new grid for a different viewport, you have to explicitly apply spans in that viewport, or it won't work. But in your case, you use different grid definitions to reproduce the same grid layout. Once your layout does not change among viewports, you don't have to declare so many various grid definitions.

Comment: > the isolation-span mixin which includes the clearing definition within the mixin and not separately afterwards. < Oh, okay. Then use `both` clearing for every first cell in a row and don't override clearing for other cells.

Comment: >just be sure not to do that in a global scope< oh excellent point. so far i haven't given much thought about the grid definition. I thought they are mandatory in the beginning for the grid definition. I think i have to rethink things a bit.